# Show Image Based on cell values automatically

Tags: vba

I'm looking for some help with my code.
I want an image to show if `'Carga volumes'` is choosen in at least one of the 3 cells. However, I need this macro to run automatically. My solution was call it on the sheet code however if the 3 cells have the same values it pastes the image 3 times. I only want it to paste once no matter how many times the `'Carga volumes'` is choosen.

Do you know how I can modify my code?

```vb
If Worksheets("Tarifário_Envios carga").Range("$D$14") = "Carga volumes" Or Worksheets("Tarifário_Envios carga").Range("$D$32") = "Carga volumes" Or Worksheets("Tarifário_Envios carga").Range("$D$50") = "Carga volumes" Then
    Worksheets("Preços_Envios Carga").Shapes("Picture 2").Copy
    Worksheets("Tarifário_Envios carga").Range("D68:D69").PasteSpecial
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you can use is the `Worksheet_Change` event which will run anytime a change is made on that worksheet.

Instead of copying and pasting your image from another worksheet, place the image where you want it on the "Tarifário_Envios carga" worksheet, and hide it.  When text is placed in the appropriate cells show it.  The shape property you can use for this is `.Visible`.  Showing/Hiding simplifies the process, pasting the image means you also need to remove the image if the text is not found.

I would also Name your image to make it easier to find if you need to reference it again.

Place this code in your "Tarifário_Envios carga" worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Only run through logic if we've modified one of these cells
    If Target.Address = "$D$14" Or Target.Address = "$D$32" Or Target.Address = "$D$50" Then
        'Set to hide image by default
        Dim oShowCargaVolumes As Boolean
        oShowCargaVolumes = False
                  
        'Mark to show image if specific text is in monitored cells
        If UCase(Me.Range("$D$14").Value) = "CARGA VOLUMES" Then oShowCargaVolumes = True
        If UCase(Me.Range("$D$32").Value) = "CARGA VOLUMES" Then oShowCargaVolumes = True
        If UCase(Me.Range("$D$50").Value) = "CARGA VOLUMES" Then oShowCargaVolumes = True
        
        'Show/Hide image
        If oShowCargaVolumes Then
            Sheet1.Shapes("imgNameHere").Visible = msoTrue
        Else
            Sheet1.Shapes("imgNameHere").Visible = msoFalse
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect Joseph ! Thank you so much